# Label/Name for Bitmap Button Field

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Currently I have 4 bitmap buttons in my application. I want to have something like Label/Name for each of the buttons so that whenever someone focus on the particular button, the name appears somewhere on the screen. It could be on top, below the buttons or anywhere will do.

How can I do this? I tried searching for bitmap button field labelling but I found nothing really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put a CustomLabelField below button fields. Override your ButtonFields `onFocus(int direction)` and `onUnfocus()` methods. Inside them invoke `setLabel(String label)` method of your CustomLabelField

```
class CustomLabelField extends Field {
    String label;
    public void setLabel(String label){
        this.label = label;
        invalidate();
    }
    protected void layout(int arg0, int arg1) {
        setExtent(Display.getWidth, getFont().getHeight());
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.Black);
        graphics.drawText(label, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT (after comments)

You can use this custom button and add your additional features in it. I did not try if this is working, but should work.

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class CustomButtonField extends BitmapField{
    private String label = "";
    private MainScreen yourScreen;

    public CustomButtonField(String label, MainScreen yourScreen) {
        super();
        this.label = label;
        this.yourScreen = yourScreen;
    }

    protected void onFocus(int direction) {
        yourScreen.setTitle(label);
        super.onFocus(direction);
    }

    protected void onUnfocus() {
        yourScreen.setTitle("");
        super.onUnfocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I would like the label to over-write the application title bar, is it possible? But it's a good help, thanks very much~

Comment: Since every buttons have their own name/label , how is the name distribution will go?

Comment: well i explained that in my answer. You need to add extra few attributes that my CustomButtonField has which are label and yourScreen. After that in onFocus and onUnfocus methods you need to set yourScreen's title this label.

Comment: Does the same method applicable if I am using bitmapbuttonfield?

Comment: Yes, you need to override these methods and add another attribute which you are going to manipulate this on BitmapButtonField.